# MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter not found with Spring4

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

I migrated my Spring framework from 3.x to 4.2.RELEASE but, when I start the jUnit I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:src/test/resources/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
```

I read on internet from Version 4.1. it's not supported anymore; I checked and the new version is available on application class path (I imported spring-web dependency). ( [Spring 4 and Rest WS integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631868/spring-4-and-rest-ws-integration) )

It seems spring is still looking for the old version of Converter. It probably depends on something I've on my application context, but, the question is, how can I "tell to Spring" to use new version?

**-- UPDATE**

I commented

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and it seems to works fine but... why?

Comment: Check your classpath, you are probably mixing different versions leading to erratic behavior.

Answer (score 13):

There's a newer version of that class in Spring 4: use `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (note the '2').

In my REST servlet's Spring config file I have it configured as follows (I added my custom objectMapper to it, but you can just omit that):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>

        <bean 
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="s3.util.json.CustomJsonMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>

    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: yeah. I know, but I don't know where to tell to spring to use this class. I'm not using directly, ti seems to be a dependency.